# Custom dashboard layout UI

Tags: android, user-interface

I have completed one android project with a `ListView` as the dashboard layout. But after seeing the pretty new wordpress dashboard I wanted to upgrade mine too. I want to make the following layout:

[image]

But after searching I found few good references here and in other site as well and finally I made mine as:

[image]

My question is how can I make the pattern like the wordpress one **typically with the unequal number of items in each row**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with  [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) widget.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess with grid layout we can equally distribute the grid on each column.Here I need unequal grids on different columns. If you look on the first image, there are 2 grids each on first and second column whereas on third and fourth there are three. How could it be done.

Comment: And sorry to mentioned but I used the Gridlayout on the one that I made on second image too

Comment: I think you are confusing GridLayout with GridView.

Comment: I could be, but I used the following reference to generate mine, http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/    And in this tutorial they say implementing Gridview layout.

Comment: Exactly, you are using GridView, but you should use GridLayout. They are different things.